# Conditional incrementing datetime difference from the starting point in new column as an integer

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, counter

**The situation:** 
I have a python/pandas dataframe with one column and the index column. The index column is a datetime format and is logged in every minute, therefore the difference between two consecutive index rows is always one minute as  the rows are sorted in index order.. The other column represents a unit id.

[image]

The "Unit_id" changes from time to time almost randomly.

**The problem:** 
I would like to add a third column named "Cycle" which counts the elapsed minutes as integers from the startpoint of given unit id till the endpoint of that unit id. Whenever there is a new unit id the counter should reset and restart from 1.

So basically I would like to look like below:

[image]

So far I tried to create a formula without the datetime index (however that would be the optimal solution) which just makes a normal counter and resets at every new Unit_id.
Here is my code:

```
def ciklus_csinalo(str_Unit_id):
    if 'old_Unit_id' in locals():
        if str_Unit_id != old_Unit_id:
            old_Unit_id = str_Unit_id
            counter = 1
            return counter
        else:
            counter += counter
            return counter
    else: 
        old_Unit_id = str_Unit_id
        counter = 1
    return counter

df["Cycle"] = df["Unit_id"].apply(ciklus_csinalo)
```

Unfortunatelly, the code is not working as I get the value of 1 in every row.

**The questions:**

1. Could you please let me know, how to add a new column which conditionally calculates the incrementally the difference between two datetimes and when the condition is met, resets and starts again from one?
2. Could you please show me how to make a column and add a conditinal incrementing counter?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this, let `data` be your `DataFrame`:

```
data['cycle'] = data.groupby('unit_id')['datetime'].transform(pd.Series.diff)
data.fillna(60, inplace=True)
data['cycle'] = data.groupby('unit_id')['cycle'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum)
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
              datetime unit_id    cycle
0  2016-10-05 08:25:00  102/16 00:01:00
1  2016-10-05 08:26:00  102/16 00:02:00
2  2016-10-05 08:27:00  102/16 00:03:00
3  2016-10-05 08:28:00  102/16 00:04:00
4  2016-10-05 08:29:00  102/16 00:05:00
5  2016-10-05 08:30:00  103/16 00:01:00
6  2016-10-05 08:31:00  103/16 00:02:00
7  2016-10-05 08:32:00  103/16 00:03:00
8  2016-10-05 08:33:00  103/16 00:04:00
9  2016-10-05 08:34:00  103/16 00:05:00
10 2016-10-05 08:35:00  104/16 00:01:00
11 2016-10-05 08:36:00  104/16 00:02:00
12 2016-10-05 08:37:00  105/16 00:01:00
13 2016-10-05 08:38:00  105/16 00:02:00
14 2016-10-05 08:39:00  105/16 00:03:00
```

If you want the last column in integers, you can do it like this:

```
data['cycle'] = data.groupby('unit_id')['cycle'].transform(pd.Series.cumsum).transform(lambda e: (e.seconds//60) % 60)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I would need the data as integer, but if I understand it correctly this is datetime format therefore it can be transformed into integer easily. Am I right?
I will try it soon and get back to you. Thank you very much again.

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, think you want `groupby` with `cumcount`:

```
df['cycle'] = df.groupby('Unit_ID').cumcount() + 1
```

Output:

```
              Datetime Unit_ID  cycle
0  2016-10-05 08:25:00  102/16      1
1  2016-10-05 08:25:01  102/16      2
2  2016-10-05 08:25:02  102/16      3
3  2016-10-05 08:25:03  102/16      4
4  2016-10-05 08:25:04  102/16      5
5  2016-10-05 08:25:05  103/16      1
6  2016-10-05 08:25:06  103/16      2
7  2016-10-05 08:25:07  103/16      3
8  2016-10-05 08:25:08  103/16      4
9  2016-10-05 08:25:09  103/16      5
10 2016-10-05 08:25:10  104/16      1
11 2016-10-05 08:25:11  104/16      2
12 2016-10-05 08:25:12  105/16      1
13 2016-10-05 08:25:13  105/16      2
14 2016-10-05 08:25:14  105/16      3
```